# Nodejs express remove data object if its in array

Tags: node.js, mongodb, express

I want to remove the data which object id is available in array. But its nested array I am doing it like this

```
const getLessonByUserid = async (req, res) => {
    const userid = req.params.userid

    try {
        const temp = [];
        const getdata = await UserLessons.find().
            populate(['quizid',
                {
                    path: 'quizid',
                    populate:
                    {
                        path: 'userid',
                        populate:
                        {
                            path: 'userid',

                        },
                    },
                }
            ]);
        let dataget = getdata;

        for (let i = 0; i < dataget.length; i++) {
            // console.log(dataget[i].quizid.length)

            for (let j = 0; j < dataget[i].quizid.length; j++) {
                console.log('debug')
                console.log(dataget[i].quizid[j])

                for (let k = 0; k < dataget[i].quizid[j].userid.length; k++) {
                    console.log(dataget[i].quizid[j].userid[k].userid);

                    if (dataget[i].quizid[j].userid[k].userid._id == req.params.id) {
                        console.log('match')
                        // dataget[i].quizid[j].userid[k].userid = [];
                        dataget[i].quizid[j].remove();
                    }
                }

            }
        }

        return res.status(200).json({
            success: true,
            message: "question found succesfully",
            data: dataget
        })

    } catch (err) {
        if (err.name === 'ValidationError') {
            console.error(Object.values(err.errors).map(val => val.message))
            return res.status(400).json({ success: false, message: Object.values(err.errors).map(val => val.message)[0] })
        }
        return res.status(400).json({ success: false, message: err.message })
    }
}
```

But the issue is `dataget[i].quizid[j].remove();` Which I need to just hide/remove is removing the data from database :D I just need to hide this array or remove array. If is there is any possibility by doing it from query that will be great.

There is 2 model

one is lesson

```
const mongoose = require('mongoose');
const lessonschema = new mongoose.Schema({
    //quiz id
    quizid: [
        {
            type: mongoose.Schema.Types.ObjectId,
            ref: "quiz"
        }
    ],
    text: {
        type: String,
        default: ''
    },
    image: {
        type: String,
        default: ''
    },
    audio: [
        {
            type: String,
            default: ''
        }

    ],
    video: [{
        type: String,
        default: ''
    }],


    createdOn: {
        type: Date,
        default: Date.now
    }

})

exports.UserLessons = mongoose.model('lessons', lessonschema);
exports.lessonschema = lessonschema;
```

Other is quiz

```
const mongoose = require('mongoose');

const quizschema = new mongoose.Schema({


    userid: [

        {
            userid: {
                type: mongoose.Schema.Types.ObjectId,
                ref: "users"
            },
            answer: {
                type: String

            }
        }

    ],
    question:
    {
        type: String,
        // required:true
    },
    questionType: {
        type: Number,
        default: 0
        //0: text,1:moodbase,

    },


    quizRating: [{
        type: mongoose.Schema.Types.ObjectId,
        ref: "answerrating"

    }],

    voice: {
        type: String,
        default: ""
    },



});

exports.Quiz = mongoose.model('quiz', quizschema)
exports.quizschema = quizschema
```

I don't know how this is removing from database. Its working fine but removing from database in not expected.

Answer (score 0):

I suggest you to use [ArrayFilters](https://www.mongodb.com/docs/manual/reference/operator/update/positional-filtered/) feature in mongodb

```
 let updatedObject = {};
 Object.assign(updatedObject, {
    'UserLessons.$[i].Quiz.$[j].quizRating.$[k].anyFieldYouWant': 
    True, // For example is boolean
  });
  this.yourModel.findOneAndUpdate(
    {
      _id: id,
    },
    updatedObject,
    {
       arrayFilters: [
        {
          'i._id': firstNestedObjectId,
        },
        {
          'j._id': secondNestedObjectId,
        },
        {
          'k._id': thirdNestedObjectId,
        },
      ],
      new: true,
    },
   );
```

This example is for update field, for removing you can use findOneAndDelete
I hope this will be useful for you